# Prove that $\psi: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z / (a) \times \mathbb Z / (b)$ is surjective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb Z$, such that they satisfy the Bezout relation $1 = sa + rb$. Let $e_1 = 1 - sa = rb$ and $e_2 = 1 - rb = sa$.
> Given the map $\psi: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z / (a) \times \mathbb Z / (b) $, $n \mapsto (n + (a), n + (b))$. Prove it is surjective using $\psi(e_1)$, $\psi(e_2)$.

I have already proved that $\psi$ is a ring homomorphism and that $\psi (e_1) = (1,0)$ and $\psi(e_2) = (0,1)$

My proof

Let $y \in \mathbb Z / (a) \times \mathbb Z / (b) $, then we have that y is a linear combination of $\psi(e_1)$, $\psi(e_2)$. And since we have that $\exists a,b \in \mathbb Z $, such that $1 = sa + rb$, $\psi$ is surjective.

Is it correct? thank you.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. Make sure you specify that $y$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of $\psi(e_1)$ and $\psi(e_2)$, as the term "linear combination" without reference to what the scalars are is not too useful.

Comment: What is a $\mathbb Z$-linear combination?

Comment: In this case, we can write $y = a \psi(e_1) + b \psi(e_2)$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. The phrase "$\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination" just refers to the fact that we're taking $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. In other contexts (e.g. linear algebra), we'd refer to linear combinations as combinations with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, for example. Once you learn about modules, you will see that I mean "a linear combination where $\mathbb{Z} / (a) \times \mathbb{Z} / (b)$ is interpreted as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module".

Comment: In your proof, the first sentence is great, and I can see easily finishing the proof from that fact about an arbitrary $y$. But to me, the second sentence of the proof is not salient; I don't see how it relates to $y$ being a linear combination, or indeed to $\psi$ at all. (Of course the fact mentioned in that second sentence was relevant to the definitions of $e_1$ and $e_2$, but that's all settled before the part of the proof in question.)

Comment: I totally agree with you. I think "since y is in the co-domain, it can be expressed as a $\mathbb Z$- linear combination of $\psi(e_1)$, $\psi(e_2)$. Would be a tad bit better.

Comment: Every post is already tagged with your username/link. Please do not add "signatures" to them.

Comment: Ok @ArturoMagidin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof as written does not seem clear to me. In particular, I'm not seeing how your second sentence follows from your first. How I would do it:

Let $y \in \mathbb{Z}/(a) \times \mathbb{Z}/(b)$, say $y=(c,d)$. We now give an integer $n$ such that $\varphi(n) = y$. This is equivalent to giving an integer $n$ such that simultaneously $n \equiv_a c$ and $n \equiv_b d$. However, the integer $n=ce_1 + de_2$ suffices.
Indeed $ce_1 \equiv_a c \times 1$ and $ce_1 \equiv_b c \times 0$, whereas $de_2 \equiv_a d \times 0$ and $de_2 \equiv_b d\times 1 =d$. Thus $ce_1+de_2 \equiv_a (c \times 1) + (d\times 0)=c$,
and likewise, $ce_1+de_2 \equiv_b d$.

Alternatively, $\varphi(n) = \varphi(ce_1)+\varphi(de_2)=$ $c\varphi(e_1)+d\varphi(e_2)=c(1,0)+d(0,1)=(c,d)=y$.

Comment: Well yes, that was where my vague idea was heading :)